# What is Gerah and how much is it?

Tags: shiurim-measurements

I would like to know what Gerah(גרה) is. Omer and Cubit are related to human body. What about Gerah? How much is Gerah in modern measurements?

Comment: Omer is 1/10 of an Eiphah ([Ex. 16:36](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0216.htm#36)). It's defined in relation to a different volume, not in relation to the human body.

Comment: @Double AA But volumes, in turn, are defined in terms of Amos (Eruvin 14a, Pesachim 109b, et. al.).

Comment: @DonielFilreis Those don't seem like definitions.

Comment: @Double AA: Chazal defined one mikveh as 40 se'ah as three cubic Amos. Or that's how I read the Gemara, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerah), the free encyclopedia:

> A gerah Hebrew "גרה" is an ancient Hebrew unit of weight and currency,
>   equivalent to one-twentieth of a shekel, a shekel being 180
>   barleycorns or 60 carob divided by 20 = 3 carob. This is 0.568 grams.

See also [here](http://www.convert-me.com/en/convert/history_weight/bibgerah.html).

Comment: Ancient units of length usually had to do with the body; ancient units of weight often involved multiples of carob seeds, as those were believed to be very consistent.

Comment: I do not accept this as the answer because it does not explain how carob seeds are connected to the word gerah. Also, carob seeds are just as inconsistent in weights as any other seeds (see Wkipedia) on what do you base your claims?

Comment: Also, how does this correspond to the weight of the Talent? With Gerah equal 3 carob, Talent weight would be 12kg. This is inconsistent with the traditional Talent.

Comment: Ibn Ezra on Ex 30:13 These gerahs (According to I.E. the word gerah is related to the word gargir [berry or pit]). refer to the pits of a carob. (A gerah weighed the same as a pit of a carob.)  [in parens are the sefaria explanations]